# filename completion within FTP session

Tags: ftp

i wonder how to make the shell auto complete filename within ftp sessions 
like in normal terminal when i press TAB by default.
for example :

```
get partialfilename..then TAB
```

to complete the filename

Comment: What's an "ftp session"? Why are you still using `ftp` (`userid` and `password` sent in clear)? And since (1) `ftp` is an old protocol, (2) filename completion would require co-operation between ftp client and server, I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

There is no tab compilation in FTP command but you can use rich command `lftp` which support tab competition .